# Set a python virtual environment to a ubuntu user?

Tags: python, bash, apache, web, virtualenv

Is it possible to activate a python virtual environment for everything a user do ? I have a webapp executing python code, and I would want the www-data user used by the apache host to use a specific python venv (It would solve a struggle for libraries).

Answer (score 0):

source the virtual environment in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I don't think www-data has a ~/.bashrc file as its a user without a login.

Comment: True, on ubuntu the default shell for www-data is nologin. You are right.

Of course, you can change the shell to bash.

However, it wont help because you can still run processes without running the shell (eg setuid, sudo ...).

I don't think you can guarantee virtualenv for a user. Maybe setting the venv for only for apache would be good enough for you?

Comment: you can activate it inside your python code:

`import os
# activate virtualenv
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/opt/ve/ve_name/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))`

Comment: @0x00 really ? Inside the python code ? And it's persistent for the lifetime of the python engine instance ?

Comment: @helper "setting the venv for only for apache would be good enough for you?" I guess so yeah. That would be great.

I tried to add a line to activate the virtual env in the apache2 start script used by systemd